# NULL in union on Apache Drill

Tags: sql, null, apache-drill, mapr

I have a query where I need to use Union to get all the dates in a single row.Does drill not support NULL in unions.Please advise,this is a sample query

```
       Select ID, Supplydate as A_SupplyDate,OrderDate as A_Orderdate,
           NULL as B_SupplyDate,NULL as B_OrderDate 
           from tbl where Category='A'
    union
       Select ID, NULL as A_SupplyDate,NULL as A_Orderdate,
           Supplydate as B_SupplyDate,OrderDate as B_OrderDate 
              from tbl where Category='B'
```

Comment: Why not try '' if null isn't working?

Comment: I want to have NULL displayed , not sure IFNULL works in this scenario

Comment: OK I see - what exactly is the error you get now?

Comment: Illegal use of NULL

Comment: Do you get the same error off a regular query without a union?

Comment: No, Regular query executes and displays NULL

Comment: Try wrapping each part of the Union into subqueries and then Union the subqueries together

Comment: Can you send me a sample query on what you mean

Comment: OK see posted answer

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, nullif(a_supplydate,'')a_supplydate, a_orderdate, nullif(b_supplydate,'')b_supplydate, b_orderdate from    
  (Select ID, Supplydate as A_SupplyDate,OrderDate as A_Orderdate,
           '' as B_SupplyDate,NULL as B_OrderDate 
           from tbl where Category='A'
    union
       Select ID, '' as A_SupplyDate,NULL as A_Orderdate,
           Supplydate as B_SupplyDate,OrderDate as B_OrderDate 
              from tbl where Category='B')A
```

Comment: ok then just put blank and then nullif the blanks - ill adjust code above

Comment: Just subsituting `nullif(1,1)` for the `null`s is enough to make it run.  Seems a bit silly.

Answer (score 0):

Cast your nulls to the appropriate data type e.g. `cast(null as bigint)`